# How to store in correct geoJSON format

Tags: javascript, mongodb, geospatial, geojson, mongoose-schema

I am trying to store some data in geoJSON format as follows.

```
var newUser = {
            'username': $('#addUser fieldset input#inputUserName').val(),
            'location': {type: "Point", coordinates: [ $('#addUser fieldset input#inputUserLocationLng').val(), $('#addUser fieldset input#inputUserLocationLat').val()]},
            'email': $('#addUser fieldset input#inputUserEmail').val(),
            'phone': $('#addUser fieldset input#inputUserPhone').val(),
            'chat': $('#addUser fieldset select#inputChatAllowed').val()                     
        }
```

And it is saved as shown below.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e327c7b8c0181090e15d445"),
    "username" : "test2",
    "location[type]" : "Point",
    "location[coordinates][]" : [
        77.641145,
        12.89149
    ],
    "email" : "test2@gmail.com",
    "phone" : "8998778987",
    "chat" : "0"
}
```

But I want the location part in correct geoJSON Format as validated [here](http://geojsonlint.com/) and shown below.

```
"location": { 
        "type" : "Point", 
        "coordinates" : [
            -73.856077, 
            40.848447
        ]
    }
```

I am using mongoose and nodejs. Any suggestions will be helpful.

Also, can a geoJSON data document in mongoDB contain non-location data (name, contact) too?

Comment: Maybe try `'location': {'type': "Point", 'coordinates': [...]}`

Comment: It didn't change anything

Comment: Shouldn't the structure look like this? Don't know what's wrong.


`location: {
        type: "Point",
        coordinates: [longitude, latitude]
    }`

Comment: How does it look when you put static numbers for lat/log values?

Comment: Then also it is same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The document looks strange. Perhaps this would be a workaround:

```
doc = db.col.insertOne({
   "username": "test2",
   "email": "test2@gmail.com",
   "phone": "8998778987",
   "chat": "0"
})

db.col.updateOne(
   { _id: doc.insertedId },
   { $set: { "location.type": "Point" } }
)

db.col.updateOne(
   { _id: doc.insertedId },
   { $push: { "location.coordinates": { $each: [-73.856077, 40.848447] } } }
)
```

or

```
db.col.updateOne(
   { _id: doc.insertedId },
   {
      $set: {
         "location": {
            type: "Point",
            coordinates: [-73.856077, 40.848447]
         }
      }
   }
)
```

or

```
db.col.updateOne(
   { _id: doc.insertedId },
   { $push: { "location.coordinates": -73.856077 } }
)

db.col.updateOne(
   { _id: doc.insertedId },
   { $push: { "location.coordinates": 40.848447 } }
)
```

Result:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e32eb3405a39c3341179e7f"), 
    "username" : "test2", 
    "email" : "test2@gmail.com", 
    "phone" : "8998778987", 
    "chat" : "0", 
    "location" : {
        "type" : "Point", 
        "coordinates" : [
            -73.856077, 
            40.848447
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using mongoose and it has some different syntax or way for doing this.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to do this in mongoose?

Comment: Should be the same: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/updating-documents.html

Comment: This worked on a test collection that I create in mongo shell.
When trying in my existing one, I get this error.  https://imgur.com/Lsntwqd